# Converting an element of a dataframe into string element - python

Tags: python, string

In python, I have such a data frame:

pn

```
Out[249]: 
   a  b   c    d    e
2  4  8  12  131  127


cn.dtypes
Out[253]: 
c1    object
c2    object
c3    object
dtype: object
```

I want to select pn["b"] as string.

When I paste below, I get the below value:

```
pn["b"]
Out[257]: 
2    8
Name: b, dtype: object
```

But I want the output to be as string:

Like below x:

```
x="8"

x
Out[259]: '8'
```

How can I do that?

I will be very glad for any help.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You mean `pn["b"].astype(str)`?

Comment: Not like that. In that way see at the output as "series" at the variable explorer window at spyder. . I just want it to be as "str".

Comment: or add that in str `str(pn["b"])`

Comment: When I do str(pn["b"]) ı get a string which has size 29. My output should be 1 size string(it is just "8")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the column `b` to string type using `astype` method and then use `iloc` to access the specific row.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> pn = pd.DataFrame({'b': [8]}, index=[2])
>>> pn
   b
2  8
>>> pn['b'].astype(str).iloc[0]
'8'
>>> type(pn['b'].astype(str).iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
```